# Use google earth(or map) offline

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-earth

I work on a mapping project with overlay images with long/lat on a world

This issue solved by Google-map or Google-earth ,

But the be problem is that the project running on a intranet without internet using

Is there anyway to use Google-map or Google-earth offline ?

If the answer is no ,Is there any software that i can use it for the project ?

thank you

Comment: Why not use OpenStreetMap instead? If you use a source like MapQuest Open tiles, you can download the images to the hard drive.

Comment: they are better maps for most of the world, and suited for off-line usage.

Comment: thanks a lot , i dont work with OpenStreetMap or MapQuest, have they overlay ability?? I found that ,i can use GeoServer or Mapserver, Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

If the system is offline, then you will need to acquire the imagery, terrain data, and vector info yourself.  You can then install GeoServer or MapServer and import the data into it. I prefer GeoServer as it has a nice user interface and is fairly idiot-proof.

Once you have a GIS server installed on your system, you can view the imagery on a site using OpenLayers or Leaflet.  I prefer leaflet, but both are fantastic solutions.

If you need data, you can export data from OpenStreetMap to your system for offline use.  There are limits, but it isn't too bad.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your attention,I installed Geoserver and openlayer and trying to make a mapserver ,but have a problem ,the problem is a sattelite map with georefrecing data ,I also try downloding map or georefrecing with ArcGIS but still cant create a map to use on Geoserver, how to download maps from Openstreetmap???

Comment: I would take a look at QGIS.  It is a great tool with a lot of plugins.  It has a plugin for downloading data directly from OSM.  I know that once you import imagery and vector data into GeoServer, you can view it from GeoServer and it will give you an example OpenLayer map.  That was my first starting point for constructing web pages with OpenLayers.  I need a lot of help as I am a C++ developer dabbling in JavaScript.  As for connecting it to ArcGIS or other third party tools, I am not familiar with them.